# Ubuntu 13.10: Can't connect to Wifi

Tags: wireless, networking, network-manager, android

I guess I'm using a very infamous Wi-fi Adapter because I've tried everything out on the internet and I guess its time to ask for individual help:

I can't seem to connect to my Wi-fi Network, I'm on a Desktop, With a Network Adapter, Network Adapter is: Netgear WNA1000M,

I know its not a distance problem or a hardware problem since I can connect to Wi-fi using Windows (I'm dual-booting Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 13.10).

and I don't have any other Hotspots so I decided to connect to an Android Hotspot and it worked. I don't know whats wrong and I need help,

The only solution right now is to USB Tether my Wi-fi using my Samsung Phone to my Computer, and its not a solution I like, I would like to use Wireless.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

- There are no error messages, It keeps trying to connect and after two minutes I get a Wireless Network: Disconnected, Error
- dmesg output:

`[   10.015356] microcode: CPU1: new patch_level=0x01000083
[   10.015370] microcode: CPU2: patch_level=0x01000039
[   10.015380] microcode: CPU2: new patch_level=0x01000083
[   10.015516] microcode: Microcode Update Driver: v2.00 <tigran@aivazian.fsnet.co.uk>, Peter Oruba
[   10.201938] usb 2-3: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c52b
[   10.201946] usb 2-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[   10.201949] usb 2-3: Product: USB Receiver
[   10.201951] usb 2-3: Manufacturer: Logitech
[   10.517730] kvm: Nested Virtualization enabled
[   10.517740] kvm: Nested Paging enabled
[   11.070492] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [AAZA] enabled at IRQ 22
[   11.070504] hda_intel: Disabling MSI
[   11.070545] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:05.0: setting latency timer to 64
[   11.070549] hda-intel 0000:00:05.0: Disabling 64bit DMA
[   11.074515] hda-intel 0000:00:05.0: Enable delay in RIRB handling
[   11.818560] hda_codec: ALC1200: SKU not ready 0x411111f0
[   11.898489] autoconfig: line_outs=4 (0x14/0x15/0x16/0x17/0x0) type:line
[   11.898496]    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   11.898498]    hp_outs=1 (0x1b/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   11.898500]    mono: mono_out=0x0
[   11.898501]    dig-out=0x11/0x0
[   11.898503]    inputs:
[   11.898505]      Front Mic=0x19
[   11.898507]      Rear Mic=0x18
[   11.898508]      Line=0x1c
[   11.898509]      Aux=0x1a
[   11.898513] realtek: No valid SSID, checking pincfg 0x411111f0 for NID 0x1d
[   11.898514] realtek: Enable default setup for auto mode as fallback
[   12.045982] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[   12.165349] hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[   12.284312] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[   12.284318] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[   12.319383] logitech-djreceiver 0003:046D:C52B.0003: hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Device [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:02.0-3/input2
[   12.324513] input: Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:4009 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/usb2/2-3/2-3:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0003/input/input3
[   12.324695] logitech-djdevice 0003:046D:C52B.0004: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:4009] on usb-0000:00:02.0-3:1
[   12.651027] rtl8192cu: Chip version 0x10
[   12.759674] rtl8192cu: MAC address: e0:46:9a:32:60:12
[   12.759682] rtl8192cu: Board Type 0
[   12.759917] rtl_usb: rx_max_size 15360, rx_urb_num 8, in_ep 1
[   12.759979] rtl8192cu: Loading firmware rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw.bin
[   12.760169] usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl8192cu
[   12.879925] type=1400 audit(1396462775.602:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" parent=448 profile="unconfined" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=449 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   12.879937] type=1400 audit(1396462775.602:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" parent=448 profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=449 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   12.879943] type=1400 audit(1396462775.602:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" parent=448 profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=449 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   12.879970] type=1400 audit(1396462775.602:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" parent=376 profile="unconfined" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=383 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   12.879985] type=1400 audit(1396462775.602:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" parent=376 profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=383 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   12.879992] type=1400 audit(1396462775.602:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" parent=376 profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=383 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   12.880724] type=1400 audit(1396462775.602:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" parent=448 profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=449 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   12.880734] type=1400 audit(1396462775.602:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" parent=448 profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=449 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   12.880775] type=1400 audit(1396462775.602:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" parent=376 profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=383 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   12.880781] type=1400 audit(1396462775.602:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" parent=376 profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=383 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   12.923561] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'rtl_rc'
[   12.924158] rtlwifi: wireless switch is on
[   13.349526] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[   13.349534] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[   13.349537] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   13.349540] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   13.349542] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   13.349543] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   13.349545] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   13.552319] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
[   13.552327] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
[   13.801071] input: HDA NVidia Front Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:05.0/sound/card0/input4
[   13.801204] input: HDA NVidia Line Out Side as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:05.0/sound/card0/input5
[   13.801308] input: HDA NVidia Line Out CLFE as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:05.0/sound/card0/input6
[   13.801408] input: HDA NVidia Line Out Surround as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:05.0/sound/card0/input7
[   13.801501] input: HDA NVidia Line Out Front as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:05.0/sound/card0/input8
[   13.801597] input: HDA NVidia Line as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:05.0/sound/card0/input9
[   13.801692] input: HDA NVidia Rear Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:05.0/sound/card0/input10
[   13.801790] input: HDA NVidia Front Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:05.0/sound/card0/input11
[   13.802644] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [AIGP] enabled at IRQ 21
[   13.802668] nvidia 0000:00:0d.0: setting latency timer to 64
[   13.802674] vgaarb: device changed decodes: PCI:0000:00:0d.0,olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=io+mem
[   13.802984] NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  304.108  Wed Jul 31 19:35:17 PDT 2013
[   13.897636] init: failsafe main process (521) killed by TERM signal
[   15.887720] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.16
[   15.887799] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[   15.887802] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   15.887823] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   15.887826] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   15.887833] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   16.123616] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   16.123640] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   16.123642] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   16.248006] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   16.248013] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   16.248038] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   16.265889] init: avahi-cups-reload main process (715) terminated with status 1
[   16.543251] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
[   19.267116] init: udev-fallback-graphics main process (862) terminated with status 1
[   21.923211] rtl8192cu: MAC auto ON okay!
[   21.955936] rtl8192cu: Tx queue select: 0x05
[   22.318236] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   22.318917] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   22.324133] forcedeth 0000:00:07.0: irq 43 for MSI/MSI-X
[   22.324180] forcedeth 0000:00:07.0 eth0: MSI enabled
[   22.324395] forcedeth 0000:00:07.0 eth0: no link during initialization
[   22.324836] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   22.325367] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[  141.264639] wlan0: authenticate with c4:39:3a:15:63:88
[  141.290695] wlan0: send auth to c4:39:3a:15:63:88 (try 1/3)
[  141.310379] wlan0: authenticated
[  141.311341] wlan0: associate with c4:39:3a:15:63:88 (try 1/3)
[  141.341940] wlan0: RX AssocResp from c4:39:3a:15:63:88 (capab=0xc11 status=0 aid=5)
[  141.342103] wlan0: associated
[  141.343566] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[  141.344148] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: US
[  141.350359] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: US
[  141.350365] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[  141.350369] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[  141.350371] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 1700 mBm)
[  141.350373] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  141.350375] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5600000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  141.350376] cfg80211:   (5650000 KHz - 5710000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  141.350378] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 3000 mBm)
[  141.350380] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm)
[  195.184578] wlan0: deauthenticating from c4:39:3a:15:63:88 by local choice (reason=3)
[  195.204481] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[  195.210009] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[  195.210017] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[  195.210020] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  195.210022] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  195.210024] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  195.210026] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  195.210027] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  215.229015] usb 1-6: USB disconnect, device number 4
[  638.077096] rtl8192cu: MAC auto ON okay!
[  638.110688] rtl8192cu: Tx queue select: 0x05
[  638.477706] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[  646.573786] wlan0: authenticate with c4:39:3a:15:63:88
[  646.598779] wlan0: send auth to c4:39:3a:15:63:88 (try 1/3)
[  646.617499] wlan0: authenticated
[  646.620877] wlan0: associate with c4:39:3a:15:63:88 (try 1/3)
[  646.632645] wlan0: RX AssocResp from c4:39:3a:15:63:88 (capab=0xc01 status=0 aid=2)
[  646.632753] wlan0: associated
[  646.633526] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[  646.634083] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: US
[  646.643670] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: US
[  646.643681] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[  646.643687] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[  646.643691] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 1700 mBm)
[  646.643695] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  646.643698] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5600000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  646.643702] cfg80211:   (5650000 KHz - 5710000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  646.643705] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 3000 mBm)
[  646.643709] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm)
[  646.644019] show_signal_msg: 180 callbacks suppressed
[  646.644025] wpa_supplicant[989]: segfault at 200000008 ip 00000000004b1795 sp 00007fff3eaf63e0 error 4 in wpa_supplicant[400000+15f000]
[  649.311097] wlan0: deauthenticating from c4:39:3a:15:63:88 by local choice (reason=2)
[  649.340167] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[  649.349652] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[  649.349663] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[  649.349669] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  649.349674] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  649.349678] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  649.349681] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  649.349685] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  650.147130] wlan0: authenticate with c4:39:3a:15:63:88
[  650.171451] wlan0: send auth to c4:39:3a:15:63:88 (try 1/3)
[  650.173091] wlan0: authenticated
[  650.173916] wlan0: associate with c4:39:3a:15:63:88 (try 1/3)
[  650.180969] wlan0: RX AssocResp from c4:39:3a:15:63:88 (capab=0xc01 status=0 aid=2)
[  650.181026] wlan0: associated
[  650.181227] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: US
[  650.188718] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: US
[  650.188728] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[  650.188734] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[  650.188738] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 1700 mBm)
[  650.188742] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  650.188746] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5600000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  650.188749] cfg80211:   (5650000 KHz - 5710000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  650.188753] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 3000 mBm)
[  650.188757] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm)
[  712.805160] wlan0: deauthenticating from c4:39:3a:15:63:88 by local choice (reason=3)
[  712.819958] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[  712.829068] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[  712.829079] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[  712.829085] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  712.829090] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  712.829094] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  712.829097] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  712.829101] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  725.371621] usb 1-6: new high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[  725.504965] usb 1-6: New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=6865
[  725.504972] usb 1-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
[  725.504977] usb 1-6: Product: SAMSUNG_Android_SPH-L710
[  725.504982] usb 1-6: Manufacturer: SAMSUNG
[  725.504985] usb 1-6: SerialNumber: 7a82037e
[  737.490716] usb 1-6: USB disconnect, device number 6
[  737.761358] usb 1-6: new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
[  737.894839] usb 1-6: New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=6863
[  737.894851] usb 1-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
[  737.894857] usb 1-6: Product: SAMSUNG_Android_SPH-L710
[  737.894862] usb 1-6: Manufacturer: SAMSUNG
[  737.894866] usb 1-6: SerialNumber: 7a82037e
[  737.966008] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ether
[  737.974913] rndis_host 1-6:1.0 usb0: register 'rndis_host' at usb-0000:00:02.1-6, RNDIS device, 02:04:56:5d:32:30
[  737.975001] usbcore: registered new interface driver rndis_host
[  873.870741] wlan0: authenticate with c4:39:3a:15:63:88
[  873.897613] wlan0: send auth to c4:39:3a:15:63:88 (try 1/3)
[  873.909169] wlan0: authenticated
[  873.910011] wlan0: associate with c4:39:3a:15:63:88 (try 1/3)
[  873.922705] wlan0: RX AssocResp from c4:39:3a:15:63:88 (capab=0xc01 status=0 aid=2)
[  873.922874] wlan0: associated
[  873.924285] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: US
[  873.943481] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: US
[  873.943489] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[  873.943492] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[  873.943495] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 1700 mBm)
[  873.943497] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  873.943498] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5600000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  873.943500] cfg80211:   (5650000 KHz - 5710000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  873.943502] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 3000 mBm)
[  873.943504] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm)
[  919.672553] wlan0: deauthenticating from c4:39:3a:15:63:88 by local choice (reason=3)
[  919.689846] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[  919.703994] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[  919.704002] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[  919.704005] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  919.704007] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  919.704009] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  919.704011] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  919.704013] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1245.421301] wlan0: authenticate with c4:39:3a:15:63:88
[ 1245.447720] wlan0: send auth to c4:39:3a:15:63:88 (try 1/3)
[ 1245.449655] wlan0: authenticated
[ 1245.452036] wlan0: associate with c4:39:3a:15:63:88 (try 1/3)
[ 1245.464247] wlan0: RX AssocResp from c4:39:3a:15:63:88 (capab=0xc01 status=0 aid=2)
[ 1245.464314] wlan0: associated
[ 1245.464643] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: US
[ 1245.473437] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: US
[ 1245.473445] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[ 1245.473448] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[ 1245.473451] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 1700 mBm)
[ 1245.473453] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1245.473454] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5600000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1245.473456] cfg80211:   (5650000 KHz - 5710000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1245.473458] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 3000 mBm)
[ 1245.473460] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm)
[ 1269.634002] usb 1-6: USB disconnect, device number 7
[ 1269.636075] rndis_host 1-6:1.0 usb0: unregister 'rndis_host' usb-0000:00:02.1-6, RNDIS device
[ 1290.554058] wlan0: deauthenticating from c4:39:3a:15:63:88 by local choice (reason=3)
[ 1290.571246] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[ 1290.578585] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[ 1290.578594] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[ 1290.578598] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1290.578600] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1290.578602] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1290.578604] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1290.578605] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1307.924514] wlan0: authenticate with 06:1d:d5:ff:10:20
[ 1307.956604] wlan0: direct probe to 06:1d:d5:ff:10:20 (try 1/3)
[ 1308.159420] wlan0: direct probe to 06:1d:d5:ff:10:20 (try 2/3)
[ 1308.363357] wlan0: direct probe to 06:1d:d5:ff:10:20 (try 3/3)
[ 1308.567359] wlan0: authentication with 06:1d:d5:ff:10:20 timed out
[ 1322.290815] usb 1-6: new high-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
[ 1322.424250] usb 1-6: New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=6865
[ 1322.424262] usb 1-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
[ 1322.424268] usb 1-6: Product: SAMSUNG_Android_SPH-L710
[ 1322.424273] usb 1-6: Manufacturer: SAMSUNG
[ 1322.424277] usb 1-6: SerialNumber: 7a82037e
[ 1396.352275] wlan0: authenticate with 34:23:ba:35:8f:7a
[ 1396.377484] wlan0: send auth to 34:23:ba:35:8f:7a (try 1/3)
[ 1396.381444] wlan0: authenticated
[ 1396.383326] wlan0: associate with 34:23:ba:35:8f:7a (try 1/3)
[ 1396.403089] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 34:23:ba:35:8f:7a (capab=0x401 status=0 aid=1)
[ 1396.403175] wlan0: associated
[ 1428.620766] wlan0: deauthenticating from 34:23:ba:35:8f:7a by local choice (reason=3)
[ 1428.635944] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[ 1428.642438] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[ 1428.642446] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[ 1428.642448] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1428.642451] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1428.642453] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1428.642455] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1428.642456] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1430.471960] wlan0: authenticate with c4:39:3a:15:63:88
[ 1430.485934] wlan0: send auth to c4:39:3a:15:63:88 (try 1/3)
[ 1430.492432] wlan0: authenticated
[ 1430.495391] wlan0: associate with c4:39:3a:15:63:88 (try 1/3)
[ 1430.502970] wlan0: RX AssocResp from c4:39:3a:15:63:88 (capab=0xc01 status=0 aid=1)
[ 1430.503089] wlan0: associated
[ 1430.503423] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: US
[ 1430.511712] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: US
[ 1430.511727] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[ 1430.511734] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[ 1430.511738] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 1700 mBm)
[ 1430.511742] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1430.511746] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5600000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1430.511749] cfg80211:   (5650000 KHz - 5710000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1430.511753] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 3000 mBm)
[ 1430.511757] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm)
[ 1476.441679] wlan0: deauthenticating from c4:39:3a:15:63:88 by local choice (reason=3)
[ 1476.455673] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[ 1476.465744] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[ 1476.465756] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[ 1476.465761] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1476.465766] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1476.465770] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1476.465774] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1476.465777] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 1496.175855] usb 1-6: USB disconnect, device number 8
[ 1496.476442] usb 1-6: new high-speed USB device number 9 using ehci-pci
[ 1496.609947] usb 1-6: New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=6863
[ 1496.609959] usb 1-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
[ 1496.609965] usb 1-6: Product: SAMSUNG_Android_SPH-L710
[ 1496.609970] usb 1-6: Manufacturer: SAMSUNG
[ 1496.609974] usb 1-6: SerialNumber: 7a82037e
[ 1496.612834] rndis_host 1-6:1.0 usb0: register 'rndis_host' at usb-0000:00:02.1-6, RNDIS device, 02:04:56:5d:32:30
[ 1748.812978] usb 1-5: USB disconnect, device number 3
[ 1748.837498] rtl_usb: reg 0x102, usbctrl_vendorreq TimeOut! status:0xffffffed value=0x0
[ 1748.837516] rtl_usb: reg 0x422, usbctrl_vendorreq TimeOut! status:0xffffffed value=0x20004
[ 1748.837527] rtl_usb: reg 0x542, usbctrl_vendorreq TimeOut! status:0xffffffed value=0x20000
[ 1748.837538] rtl_usb: reg 0x608, usbctrl_vendorreq TimeOut! status:0xffffffed value=0x83040000
[ 2996.422443] usb 1-5: new high-speed USB device number 10 using ehci-pci
[ 2996.556116] usb 1-5: New USB device found, idVendor=0846, idProduct=9041
[ 2996.556123] usb 1-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 2996.556129] usb 1-5: Product: 802.11n WLAN Adapter
[ 2996.556133] usb 1-5: Manufacturer: Realtek
[ 2996.556137] usb 1-5: SerialNumber: 00e04c000001
[ 2996.556984] rtl8192cu: Chip version 0x10
[ 2996.665773] rtl8192cu: MAC address: e0:46:9a:32:60:12
[ 2996.665779] rtl8192cu: Board Type 0
[ 2996.666017] rtl_usb: rx_max_size 15360, rx_urb_num 8, in_ep 1
[ 2996.666097] rtl8192cu: Loading firmware rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw.bin
[ 2996.666570] ieee80211 phy1: Selected rate control algorithm 'rtl_rc'
[ 2996.667782] rtlwifi: wireless switch is on
[ 2996.723342] rtl8192cu: MAC auto ON okay!
[ 2996.776310] rtl8192cu: Tx queue select: 0x05
[ 2997.151971] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[ 2997.152724] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[ 3028.736827] wlan0: authenticate with c4:39:3a:15:63:88
[ 3028.762330] wlan0: send auth to c4:39:3a:15:63:88 (try 1/3)
[ 3028.765942] wlan0: authenticated
[ 3028.768172] wlan0: associate with c4:39:3a:15:63:88 (try 1/3)
[ 3028.793369] wlan0: RX AssocResp from c4:39:3a:15:63:88 (capab=0xc01 status=0 aid=1)
[ 3028.793444] wlan0: associated
[ 3028.793639] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[ 3028.795107] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: US
[ 3028.805585] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: US
[ 3028.805598] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[ 3028.805603] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[ 3028.805608] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 1700 mBm)
[ 3028.805612] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 3028.805615] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5600000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 3028.805618] cfg80211:   (5650000 KHz - 5710000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 3028.805622] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 3000 mBm)
[ 3028.805625] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm)`

- Iwconfig Output:

  alan@alan-ubuntu:~$ iwconfig
  usb0      no wireless extensions.

  eth0      no wireless extensions.

  lo        no wireless extensions.

  wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any
            Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm
            Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
            Power Management:off
- Removed the password still the same issue.

Sorry for all this weird formatting, I barely registered today and don't really know how to use these formating options.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify a few things: 1) Are there any error messages? Also check the output of `dmesg` just after attempting to connect 2) Is your wireless card recognized correctly? Please post the output of `iwconfig`. 3) Try temporarily removing the password from your network. Can you connect now? Just to narrow down the possible problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Netgear WNA1000M is Realteck chipset RTL8188CUS, which is supported by [rtlwifi](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/rtl819x) driver,
but you can also try with [ndiswrapper](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ndiswrapper/index.php?title=Main_Page).

To install rtlwifi:

[Download](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Download#Directly_downloading_the_tarball) driver on your Desktop, then extract it.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential
cd ~/Desktop/compat- (complete with tab)
./scripts/driver-select rtlwifi
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rtl8192cu
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you instruct me on installing this "rtlwifi" driver please?

Comment: 1) Do I got to linux-stable backports releases or
linux-next backports releases
2) Both of them take me to a directory, which folder should i download?

Sorry for being so nooby, and thank you so much for helping.

Comment: linux-stable backport is fine. You need to choose the version of the kernel you are using. `uname -a` if you don't know.

Comment: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new

Answer (score 0):

Open UBUNTU Update app at the last tab you will find hardware that was not installed. click on the install and you are ready to go.

Some drivers need your permission to be installed because of legal issues.

Comment: That's "Software Updater" right? Or where can I find Ubuntu Update App. If your speaking of "Additional Drivers" tab, there is only an Nvidia Geforce Driver.

Comment: Not sure about the name in English, my Ubuntu is in spanish; but it's the one with an "A" in the icon.
In  my Laptop I need to go there to install my WiFi; I do it every time I reinstall Ubuntu

Comment: Yes thats Software Updater, I went onto the last tab like you said which is "Addition Drivers" and it only shows Nvidia Graphics Drivers.